# How to emulate JSON_OVERLAPS function on MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql

I have two columns from different tables that hold JSON-formatted data. The data stored in both columns are arrays. Example:

**`users`**

```
+----+------------------+
| id | options          |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | ["AB","CD","XY"] |
|  2 | ["CD","GH"]      |
+----+------------------+
```

**`items`**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | options     |
+----+-------------+
| 10 | ["CD","EF"] |
| 11 | ["GH","XY"] |
| 12 | ["GH"]      |
+----+-------------+
```

I wanted to write a query that returns all the rows from `users` which matches a given row from `items`, using `options` columns to perform the match. The rule is if any value in the array is present in both rows, they are a match. Example: user 1 would match items 10 (because of `CD` option) and 11 (because of `XY` option); user 2 would match items 10, 11 and 12 because all of them have `CD` or `GH`.

Looking at MySQL docs I found that [`JSON_OVERLAPS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps) does exactly that. However, I'm running MySQL 5.7 and the function is only available starting at 8.0.17. There is also no much talking around this function on the web.

How could I emulate `JSON_OVERLAPS` behavior on MySQL 5.7 in a query?

**Edit**: Unfortunately, upgrading to MySQL 8 is not an option since we run MariaDB on production, which also doesn't have that function.

Comment: Upgrading seems simpler

Comment: @Strawberry I thought someone would suggest that so I just edited the question to inform that we run MariaDB on production. But thanks, anyway.

Comment: i posted a answer, which i believe should also work on MariaDB ~10.2+ (i believe) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to emulate JSON_OVERLAPS function on MySQL 5.7?
>
> Edit: Unfortunately, upgrading to MySQL 8 is not an option since we run MariaDB on production, which also doesn't have that function.

**Be warned like  Strawberry, suggested already upgrading is more easy**

Now that is out off the way. You still asked for it, lets have some fun.
I posted some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2548147+JSON_TABLE) in the past to simulate MySQL's 8 `JSON_TABLE()`, why did i mention this? Because i use this method to emulate MySQL's 8 `JSON_OVERLAPS` to simply JOIN both resultsets which emulate `JSON_TABLE()` to a final resultset

Which makes the query below (forgive the formatting)

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

SELECT
    items.id
  ,    JSON_UNQUOTE(
       JSON_EXTRACT(items.options, CONCAT('$[', number_generator.number , ']'))
     ) AS json_options
                     
                                
FROM (

  SELECT 
   @items_row := @items_row + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION   SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION  SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @items_row := -1 
  ) init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN (


SELECT 
    items.id
  , items.options
  , JSON_LENGTH(items.options) AS json_array_length    
FROM 
   items

) AS items 
WHERE
    number BETWEEN 0 AND  json_array_length - 1   
                    
) AS items 
INNER JOIN (

  SELECT
    users.id
  ,    JSON_UNQUOTE(
       JSON_EXTRACT(users.options, CONCAT('$[', number_generator.number , ']'))
     ) AS json_options
                     
                                
FROM (

  SELECT 
   @users_row := @users_row + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION   SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION  SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @users_row := -1 
  ) init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN (


SELECT 
    users.id
  , users.options
  , JSON_LENGTH(users.options) AS json_array_length    
FROM 
   users

) AS users 
WHERE
    number BETWEEN 0 AND  json_array_length - 1   
) AS users 
USING(json_options)
```

**Result**

```
| json_options | id  | id  |
| ------------ | --- | --- |
| CD           | 10  | 2   |
| CD           | 10  | 1   |
| GH           | 11  | 2   |
| GH           | 12  | 2   |
| XY           | 11  | 1   |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9tcgRBJJcGrEsSPEAfmPzq/5)

Comment: Hey! In spite of being a huge query, it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: *"In spite of being a huge query"* Well sorry never said it would be easy .. @GustavoStraube , hope you could worked it out how it works..