# Is there a possibility to find member of in two array containing "ANY" not "ALL" mysql json

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Im trying to search an array within an existing one in MySQL for contains check, with the condition that even if a single element is intersecting result is true.

Tried existing functions - JSON_CONTAINS / MEMBER OF. But they seem to check "ALL" condition.

```
SET @j1 = '["a","b","c"]';
SET @j2 = '["d","e","f","a"]';

SELECT <OPERATOR>(J1,J2);
+------------------------+
|                      1 |
+------------------------+
```

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> select json_overlaps(@j1, @j2);
+-------------------------+
| json_overlaps(@j1, @j2) |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
```

Requires MySQL 8.0. If you're still on MySQL 5.x, see [How to emulate JSON_OVERLAPS function on MySQL 5.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071210/how-to-emulate-json-overlaps-function-on-mysql-5-7)